# Error en Indices compuestos SQL

Tags: sql

- Cree un Índice único compuesto (nombre y dirección del Proveedor) ordenado de forma descendente, incluir el campo ciudad

```
Create unique index idxProveedor
on VENT.Proveedor(NombreProveedor,Direccion)
include(Ciudad)
order by NombreProveedor desc, Direccion desc
go
```

en el `order by` me sale error.
Alguien me puede decir como solucionarlo

Comment: Cual es el error que tienes?

Answer (score 0):

El orden que quieres en las columnas de los índices no se especifica con `ORDER BY`, sino de la siguiente forma:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idxProveedor ON VENT.Proveedor(NombreProveedor DESC,Direccion DESC) 
INCLUDE(Ciudad) 
;
```

Por defecto las columnas se ordenan de forma ascendiente, con lo que no es necesario agregar nada en ese caso.